# Means based on column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate the mean of the below data frame based on the index. My data  has the following form.

```
  index  t1  t2  t3  t4
    10   1    4   7   10
    20   2    5   8   11
    30   3    6   9   0
    40   1    0   0   0
```

I defined the following steps to calculate the means of index column:

`Step 1:` Sum columns based on time-steps:

```
 index  t1   t2  t3  t4  sum
    10  1    4   7   10  22
    20  2    5   8   11  26
    30  3    6   9   0   18
    40  0    1   0   0   1
```

`Step 2:` Following the sum variable create a data frame to calculate the means of `index`

```
    10 20 30 40 
    10 20 30 
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20 30
    10 20
    10 20
    10 20
    10 20
       20
       20
       20
       20
```

I don't know how to create the df at step 2 (eg. how to return the number of occurrences based on sum value)

---

Data sample:

```
df<-structure(list(index=c (10,20,30,40), 
                   t1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1), 
                   t2 = c(4, 5, 6, 0), 
                   t3 = c(7, 8,9,  0),
                   t4 = c(10, 11, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take `sum` of rows using `rowSums` and then repeat index value `sum` times.

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df[-1])
lst <- Map(rep, df$index, df$sum)
sapply(lst, `[`, 1:max(lengths(lst)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   10   20   30   40
# [2,]   10   20   30   NA
# [3,]   10   20   30   NA
# [4,]   10   20   30   NA
# [5,]   10   20   30   NA
# [6,]   10   20   30   NA
# [7,]   10   20   30   NA
# [8,]   10   20   30   NA
# [9,]   10   20   30   NA
#[10,]   10   20   30   NA
#[11,]   10   20   30   NA
#[12,]   10   20   30   NA
#[13,]   10   20   30   NA
#[14,]   10   20   30   NA
#[15,]   10   20   30   NA
#[16,]   10   20   30   NA
#[17,]   10   20   30   NA
#[18,]   10   20   30   NA
#[19,]   10   20   NA   NA
#[20,]   10   20   NA   NA
#[21,]   10   20   NA   NA
#[22,]   10   20   NA   NA
#[23,]   NA   20   NA   NA
#[24,]   NA   20   NA   NA
#[25,]   NA   20   NA   NA
#[26,]   NA   20   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with base R that returns a Dataframe at the end.

```
x <- rep(df$index, rowSums(df[-1]))
x <- split(x,x)
x <- lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x)))
data.frame(x)
#>    X10 X20 X30 X40
#> 1   10  20  30  40
#> 2   10  20  30  NA
#> 3   10  20  30  NA
#> 4   10  20  30  NA
#> 5   10  20  30  NA
#> 6   10  20  30  NA
#> 7   10  20  30  NA
#> 8   10  20  30  NA
#> 9   10  20  30  NA
#> 10  10  20  30  NA
#> 11  10  20  30  NA
#> 12  10  20  30  NA
#> 13  10  20  30  NA
#> 14  10  20  30  NA
#> 15  10  20  30  NA
#> 16  10  20  30  NA
#> 17  10  20  30  NA
#> 18  10  20  30  NA
#> 19  10  20  NA  NA
#> 20  10  20  NA  NA
#> 21  10  20  NA  NA
#> 22  10  20  NA  NA
#> 23  NA  20  NA  NA
#> 24  NA  20  NA  NA
#> 25  NA  20  NA  NA
#> 26  NA  20  NA  NA
```